# Fill div with vertical or horizontal lines

Tags: html, css

How do I fill a `div` with vertical or horizontal lines? I did this last year, can't find the code and have no idea what to search for other than "fill div with lines" which yields no related results.

Here's a pic to show what I mean:

[image]

I really would prefer to do this with pure CSS, if possible.

Comment: have you tried a repeated background-image or linear-gradient ?

Comment: you mean you want to add noteline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try using a CSS linear-gradient that is oriented horizontally and repeats along the same axis:

```
div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #c8d9ff 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-size: 4px 100%;
}
```

We only need to specify the middle colour stop (at 50%), because with the 0% and 100% stops ignored the browser's rendering engine will automatically extrapolate the colours on each end from the two middle colour stops. This is the equivalent of the longer (and unnecessary) code:

```
div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #c8d9ff 0%, #c8d9ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
    background-size: 4px 100%;
}
```

### Notes:

1. You might want to add vendor prefixes for this, since the latest `linear-gradient` specification might not be supported across all browsers, depending on your user demographic.
2. You might want to specify a solid `background-color` for older browsers to fall back to.

See proof-of-concept example here: <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/xmaSe/)</kbd>

Comment: I have just replaced background-image with simpy background and it still works the same. Is this still valid though? I feel kinda dirty using background-image, cause it's not an image.

Comment: `background` is simply a shorthand for various properties: `-color`, `-repeat`, `-position`, `-image`... I would prefer enumerating them individually.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you need just lines?? or a small divs inside div?

For horizontal line, you can use following tag.

```
<hr/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do it with a repeating linear gradient.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nmL78/):

HTML:

```
<div class="stripe"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.stripe{
    background-color: blue;
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    top:50px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Adjust the CSS at will...

Comment: this is simply a solid-colored `div`. It contains no lines.